# storyboard exlude tabbar for single view

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

In my application I have a Tabbar Controller which contains 6 views. The second view is a Navigation Controller which contains 2 other views. Now I want these 2 views to not show the tabbar form the Tabbar Controller which contains all these views. Is this possible with storyboard or in my whole view structure incorrect?

**EDIT**
It is basically the same when you press on a user in the app WhatsApp from the Chats tab and you go to the chatview for that user.

Comment: The same happens with whatsapp when you select a user and the chat history shows up (from the "Chats" tab)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, when you press on tab 2, do you want the tab bar to disappear immediately or when a new view is pushed onto tab 2's navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

did the trick.

So when a user clicks on tab 2 a tableview shows up. Then when clicking one a cell a new view shows up without the tabbar.

Comment: There is also a "Hides Bottom Bar on Push" checkbox for view controller in Interface Builder.